# How to pass props from container component to redux form(component) - react using typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-form, react-props

I have one Form container component:

```
class PersonalDetailContainer extends React.Component<PropTypes> {
  onSubmit = async (fields: PersonalFields) => {
    this.props.savePersonalDetail(fields);
  };

  render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
          <div>
            <PersonalDetail onSubmit={this.onSubmit} id="id" />
             <!-- onSubmit props working fine but id props not working fine
             **error: [ts] Property 'id' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<FormInstance<{}, Partial<ConfigProps<{}, {}>>>> & ...'.**
            -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  savePersonalDetail: savePersonalDetail,
};
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(PersonalDetailContainer);
```

**in Form component:**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Field, InjectedFormProps, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { renderInput } from '../../../utils/input-field';

export type PersonalFields = {
  name?: string;

};

interface PersonalProps extends InjectedFormProps {
  id: string;
  onSubmit({ name }: PersonalFields): void;
}

class PersonalDetail extends React.Component<PersonalProps, PersonalFields> {
  state: PersonalFields = {};

  onChangeSetToState = (stateKey: string) => (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
    this.setState({ [stateKey]: e.currentTarget.value.trim() });

  onSubmit = () => {
    this.props.onSubmit(this.state);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
          <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>
            <Field
              name="name"
              id="name"
              component={renderInput}
              value={this.state.name}
              type="text"
              placeholder="Name"
              onChange={this.onChangeSetToState('name')}
            />
            <div className="loginBtnContainer">
              <button className="btn primaryButton" type="submit">
                Update
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default reduxForm({ form: 'personalForm' })(PersonalDetail);
```

in container, `onSubmit` passing properly to child component but `id` props not passing properly. it's throwing error:

**[ts] Property 'id' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes>>> & ...'.**

How to solve this error ?
Thanks :)

Comment: i think its because PersonalProps doesnt have and Id defined in the interface. why dont you put the type as any. class PersonalDetail extends React.Component<any, any>

Comment: or add the field 'id' to personal props interface.

Comment: added id:string, but not working. getting same issue

Answer (score 1):

its because your interface personalprops doesnt have an id field defined.

```
 interface PersonalProps extends InjectedFormProps {
    onSubmit({ name }: PersonalFields): void;
    id:any; 
 }
```

add this and it will remove the rror

Comment: after adding id:any getting same issue

Comment: you have not initialized the state anywhere in PersonalDetail . though dont this it is related to this error.

Comment: also try  class PersonalDetail extends React.Component<any, any> {

Comment: React.Component<any, any> this is working fine.  to avoid error i can do this, but this is not a proper solution.

Comment: well adding id to your interface should have corrected the the error. i dont know why its not

Comment: can you update the version of typescript you are using

Comment: React.Component<any, any> also not working. can you check similar bounty question there :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48651100/property-isloading-does-not-exist-on-type-intrinsicattributes-intrinsicclas

Comment: I found it was because of the @types I had installed. I removed that and it started working fine