# Property 'isLoading' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<FormInstance<{}, Partial<ConfigProps<{}, {}>> -Redux form

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-form, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I have one container component and one form component:

**Form component:**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { reduxForm, Field, InjectedFormProps } from 'redux-form';

export type LoginState = {
  email: string;
  password: string;
};

interface LoginProps extends InjectedFormProps {
  isLoading: boolean;
  onSubmit(userCredential: LoginState): void;
}

class Login extends React.Component<LoginProps, LoginState> {
  constructor(props: LoginProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      otp: '',
    };
  }
  onEmailChange = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    this.setState({ email: e.currentTarget.value.trim() });
  };

  onPasswordChange = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    this.setState({ password: e.currentTarget.value.trim() });
  };

  onSubmit = () => {
    this.props.onSubmit(this.state);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3 className="ac-section__title">Login</h3>
        <div className="ac-section__body">
          <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>
            <Field
              name="email"
              placeholder="Email"
              component={renderInput}
              type="email"
              value={this.state.email}
              onChange={this.onEmailChange}
              validate={[required, email]}
            />
            <Field
              name="password"
              placeholder="Password"
              component={renderInput}
              type="password"
              value={this.state.password}
              onChange={this.onPasswordChange}
              validate={required}
            />
            <br />
            <div className="loginBtnContainer">
              <button className="btn primaryButton" type="submit">
                Login
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
          <div className="ac-password__wrapper">
            <Link to="/forgot-password" className="ac-password-link">
              Forgot your password?
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default reduxForm({ form: 'loginForm' })(Login);
```

**Container component:**

```
return (
      <div>
         <Login onSubmit={this.onSubmit} isLoading={true} />  
         /* here throwing error: Property 'isLoading' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<FormInstance<{}, Partial<ConfigProps<{}, {}>>>> & ...'. */

      </div>
    );
```

here `isLoading` is not passing as a props to form component. please help me out with a good solution.

Thanks :)

Comment: can you check if you have installed the typings or @types for redux-form? if yes try removing them, else try installing them. I have found that in some cases the typing cause extra problems than solving issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Redux Form](https://redux-form.com) is a very efficient approach for form handling and validation in React + Redux environments. Here the issue you are having looks to be about missing props, and a few interface definitions. I have provided a sandbox at the end.

A solution could be to specify the form interface by yourself, something like this:

```
export interface FormInterface {
  handleSubmit: PropTypes.func; 
  handleChange?: PropTypes.func;
  reset?: PropTypes.func;
  pristine?: PropTypes.bool;
  submitting?: PropTypes.bool;
  error?: PropTypes.bool;
  invalid?: PropTypes.bool;
  submitSucceeded?: PropTypes.bool;
  submitFailed?: PropTypes.bool;
  anyTouched?: PropTypes.bool;
}
```

and use that to derive `LoginProps` from. Then typescript won't complain about missing props, which is apparently the way redux form works.

See this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/x3kq4p22ow) for details. I have gone over a few minor stuff for you, as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i implement this as you suggested, but facing issue  like func is not defined on PropTypes because of type definition.

Comment: If you post the code snippet here, I can take a look at it

Comment: Please check this:
https://codesandbox.io/s/5045y9pj84
I am getting error on line no. 111 in hello.tsx file
please hover on Login (export default reduxForm({ form: "loginForm" })(Login)). you will see error i am getting.